# voice reading web pages (news articles) on the iPhone and Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, web-browsing, text-to-speech, voice

I am looking for an app or a method to easily read aloud web pages (especially news articles) that I find on the web.

I read possible 20-50 news articles a day and most of them I would just like to listen to being read by an electronic voice.

I have actually had some success using the built in accessibility features of the mac - however I find them clumsy and difficult to use.

Notes how I used to use the accessibility features:

1. I would make the set the text to voice short cut to #s
2. I would highlight the text by selecting it in the browser
3. I would then #s to start reading the text

Problems with this approach:

1. There is no easy way to pause the reading of the text
2. The the select + read is rather cumbersome
3. There is no way to batch the reads
4. There is no queue of reads ... like you can't throw stuff conveniently in the the read queue

Actually what I am looking for is a getpocket.com equivalent of text-to-speech.

Comment: The accessibility features you mention are what people usually use for this kind of thing. Can you describe in a bit more detail why you consider them clumsy/difficult and what a "good" solution/UI would look like for you?

Comment: @patrix, I added notes as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the service "Add to iTunes as a spoken track"? You can easily assign a keyboard shortcut to it an then manage the tracks with iTunes.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpySx0yajEo) on youtube.